# Learning TTD Rspec. cant load require relative file

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

im trying to practise TDD and rspec. im testing a method that returns someone age from a year of birth argument.
however when i run rspec it cant read the require relative file. im not sure why.
also i was wondering if i am doing anything else wrong. thanks.

```html
require "date"
def current_age_for_birth_year(birthyear)
  year = Date.today.year
  puts birthyear - year
end
```

```html
require_relative '../current_age_for_birth_year'

describe "current_age_for_birth_year method" do
  it "returns the age of a person based on the year of birth" do
    age_of_person = current_age_for_birth_year(1984)

    expect(age_of_person).to eq(19)
  end
end
```

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "rspec"
```

```html
  testing rspec

An error occurred while loading ./spec/current_age_for_birth_year_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require_relative 'current_age_for_birth_year'

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- /Users/benherring/testing/spec/current_age_for_birth_year
# ./spec/current_age_for_birth_year_spec.rb:1:in `require_relative'
# ./spec/current_age_for_birth_year_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00027 seconds (files took 0.10919 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

[image]

Comment: Updated my answer with file structure tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you want is up one directory, but then nested down one in `app` folder so instead, try this

```
require_relative '../app/current_age_for_birth_year'
```

On a side note, it looks like you created your Gemfile in the spec folder, but you normally want to keep the Gemfile in the root of your project folder, so in this case you probably want to move

```
test/spec/Gemfile
test/spec/Gemfile.lock
```

up one level to:

```
test/Gemfile
test/Gemfile.lock
```

From the looks of it there's really nothing in your Gemfile anyway but that should be your typical file structure.